# Ratio policy for Intersect in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: intersection, arcgis-online, feature-layer, splitting, apportion

I have two polygon layers in ArcGIS Online (for organizations) stored as Feature Layers; one is population block, another is the AOI polygon. They are overlapping and I want to find out what portion of the population is "located" within the AOI polygon.

[image]

I used to do that in ArcGIS Desktop by creating a [Feature Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000006p000000) with Use Ratio Policy option with Make Feature Layer GP tool and then running Intersect GP tool (which will respect the field ratio settings). An easy thing.

I cannot find a way to do this in ArcGIS Online though. Overlay with Intersect method doesn't split the attribute value; Summarize Within doesn't clip the area and of course no value splitting either. Which tool/workflow should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a specific example, just a couple of suggestions- couldn't you do this with 'summarize within':

https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/use-maps/perform-analysis.htm

...more specifically documented here, and although I haven't tested, it seems you could make use of 'percentShape' after specifying 'groupbyfield' (not sure if you already tried that):

https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/analysis/api-reference/summarize-within.htm

Otherwise, as a workaround, download to a temp gdb and proceed as you've already specified with a feature layer ratio.

Comment: Got it working with Summarize within. I should have missed some option when running the tool earlier. Now it works splitting the attribute.